# Asking for input in python, allow direct entry or a text file

Tags: python, file, input

Is it possible to use a typical x=input('') where someone could either do a direct entry, or they can say read from a file?
Example:

```
x=input("")
for line in x:
    print('Hi %s'%line)
```

The person can then either type their name, or put a text file to read from? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Use a try and except to see if the passed string is a valid path:

```
x = input()

try:
    with open(x) as data:
        for name_line in data:
            print('Hi ' + name_line)

except:
    print('Hi ' + x)
```

Comment: I would do `except EnvironmentError` but this is the right idea for sure.